# Exponential Integral solving

Tags: integration

We can solve a gaussian integral using cauchy's integral formula:

$$\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty} e^ {-z^2}= \sqrt{\pi}$$

What if I change the limit to $$\int_{0}^{ 1} e^ {-z^2} \ \ \ ? $$

Is there any easy way to solve this?

Comment: There is no *known* combination so far in terms of *standard constants* to express it. We just write $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\:\text{erf}(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

[The Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) should be used if you want to compute it as defined integral. You can easily find tables with its values or compute it directly in any computer algebra system like Wolfram Mathematica.